# CSS doesn't work on single div, others get changed

Tags: css, html

I'm currently working on a website design and need to make some changes to an advertisement. The CSS I apply to the main div (.ad_728x90_home) I'm targeting doesn't work. I have applied a margin-top to the div but that doesn't work, tried other CSS but it's not getting picked up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! The advert is located below the second post.

```
.ad_728x90_home {
height: 130px;
}

.ad_728x90_home_text {
margin-top: 40px;
}

span.ad_728x90_home_h3text {
color: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
font-family: LeagueGothicRegular;
font-size: 23px;
line-height: 34px;
margin: 13px 0 22px 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 185px;
}

.ad_728x90_image {
float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
}

        <div class="ad_728x90_home">

            <div class="ad_728x90_home_text">
                <span class="ad_728x90_home_h3text">Need more quality fonts? Head over to myfonts.com</span>
            </div>

            <div class="ad_728x90_image">
                <img class="scale-with-grid" src="images/ad_728x90.jpg" alt="Blog Post" />
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't tell us what you expect to happen vs what does happen. How are we supposed to deduce what you wanted to do, from code that -- by your own admission -- _doesn't_ describe that thing? Chicken and the egg...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have the right class names between .ad_728x90_home and .ad_728x90_home_text and double check your HTML nesting.

I checked your items with Chrome's inspect element and the `<div class="ad_728x90_home_text">` seems to start above your ad, at the top of the page.

Comment: I can't seem to find where that div supposedly begins. I can't find a single reference to the div I'm working on yet a yellow border-bottom applied does appear at the top of first post. So I don't know where it's coming from. Any ideas? http://i.imgur.com/gH9L5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try going to make it a position:relative as it seems like a main div element

```
.ad_728x90_home {
Postion:relative;
top:10px;}
```

I cannot say the exact pixel amount of it as the margin-top doesnt work try using it as relative.

Comment: While this works, I still can't figure why I can't add a margin or a border-bottom (ends up at the top of the page). Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: "top" is for tweak an element with use of "position" property. margin-top is for measuring the external distance to the element, in relation to the previous one.
Also, top behavior can differ depending on the type of position, absolute, relative or fixed.And div has a default block set on it.When a child div been declared in the parent Div.providing the width of the block would also relsove our problem.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Adding a width to .ad_728x90_home (or any of the underlying div's) did not work.

Comment: as said by @Alvin Reyes <div class="ad_728x90_home_text"> seems to start above your ad, at the top of the page. So you want the margin-top or border changes to be affected to the rest of the page as well.or only to this particular div.As the postion:relative will only work to that particular Div but not to the rest of the page.

Comment: But that advert code has only been placed once below the second post, I don't understand how it's possible the advert div is starting at the top of the page. I have checked for any references but I can't see it.